# PHP How to do htmlspecialchars() when i have preg_replace

Tags: php, html, preg-replace, html-entities, htmlspecialchars

If I'm making a forum, guestbook, comment section etc. in PHP, and someone inputs text such as hi and instead of it showing up in red, it shows up as raw text. I've tried using htmlentites() and htmlspecialchars() but the thing is I'm doing a preg_replace() to replace bbcode tags as html tags, like a forum system. If i use htmlspecialchars() before the replace, it doesn't work. However, if I use htmlspecialchars() after the replace, it displays the html tags that i converted as raw text.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>BBCODE TEST</title>
<link rel=stylesheet href="bbcode.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="bbcode.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$form = "<form method='post' action=''>
<input type='textbox' class='textbox' name='textbox' onKeyPress='return check(event)'/>
<input type='submit' class='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>";

if (isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['textbox'])){

$text = $_POST['textbox'];
$text = bbcode($text);

echo $text;
echo $form;
} else {
echo $form;
}

function bbcode($text){

$text = $_POST['textbox'];

$patterns = array(
"/\[url=(.+)\](.*)\[\/url\]/is" => "<a href='\\1'>\\2</a>",
"/\[img\](.+)\[\/img\]/is" => "<img src='\\1' />",
"/\[b\](.+)\[\/b\]/is" => "<b>\\1</b>",
"/\[i\](.+)\[\/i\]/is" => "<i>\\1</i>",
"/\[u\](.+)\[\/u\]/is" => "<u>\\1</u>",
"/\[color=(.+)\](.*)\[\/color\]/is" => "<font color='\\1'>\\2</font>"
);

foreach($patterns as $pattern => $replace){
$text = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $text);
}

return $text;

}


?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hint: use preg_split and/or preg_replace_callback

Comment: DO not completely follow.